# Single JS function to replace multiple strings

Tags: javascript

I have the ability to include basic Javascript functions in a web-app (FormAssembly) and I need it to parse and do some string replacement. I don't know JS and have been struggling to figure out how to get the proper syntax and logic, so hopefully this makes sense.

An example of an allowed Javascript function in this app is: `if(var=="banana"){"banana;"}else{""}`

The input text `var` can be in the form of a few fruits, just as `banana`, `bananagrape`, or `bananagrapekiwi`. There are up to 5 values, and I know all the possible values. Basically I want to append a semicolon `;` character to all the fruits so that the output text would be `banana;` or `banana;grape;kiwi;`

Here's what I've come up with. I'm not able to retrieve error message from this web app FormAssembly so I can't tell what's not working:

```
<script>
const parseFruit = (val) => {
    return val.replace(/banana/g,"banana;").replace(/kiwi/g,"kiwi;")
    }
</script>
```

Any help to get the proper syntax would be appreciated

Update: looks like the initial function is working for input parameters that don't have any spaces. How would I include spaces in the first parameter in the `replace` function?

```
<script>
const parseFruit = (val) => {
    return val.replace(/banana/g,"banana;").replace(/other fruit/g,"other fruit;")
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It works fine for me; what is your output?

Comment: Your function seems to work, but are you just calling it? Where and how is it called? PS: does it work any better with the other variant you give, `if(var=="banana"){"banana;"}else{""}` ?

Comment: Yeah looks like it's working. THe app outputs `error` if there's no input at first. Updating the question to include another scenario of spaces in the input.

Comment: @simplycoding then I guess `val` could be `undefined`, that would explain the error. Try surrounding with `if (val === undefined) { return ""; } else { return val.replace(...) }`

Answer (score 3):

You could create an [alternation](https://javascript.info/regexp-alternation) and replace the matches with an extra `;`

[`$&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) gets the matched substring

```js
const parseFruit = val => val.replace(/banana|kiwi|grape/g, "$&;")

console.log(parseFruit("bananagrapekiwi"))
console.log(parseFruit("bananakiwi"))
```

If you have an array of fruits, you could create a dynamic alternation by joining the array with `|` and [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor

```js
const fruits = ["banana", "kiwi", "grape", "apple", "mango"],
      regex = new RegExp(fruits.join("|"), 'g');

const parseFruit = val => val.replace(regex, "$&;")

console.log(parseFruit("bananagrapekiwi"))
console.log(parseFruit("grapeapplemango"))
console.log(parseFruit("applebanana"))
```